# pyarrow hdfs.connect on windows

Tags: windows, hdfs, pyarrow

i want to use pyarrow to read and write frome a hdfs.

I installed hadoop on my Windows 10 64 bit system as on:
https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10
And installed pyarrow with pip.

But if i want to connect to hdfs in python i get the following error:

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow.hdfs.connect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\TIKI_git\ai-core-python\venv\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py", line 183, in connect
    extra_conf=extra_conf)
  File "C:\TIKI_git\ai-core-python\venv\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._connect(host, port, user, kerb_ticket, driver, extra_conf)
  File "pyarrow\io-hdfs.pxi", line 89, in pyarrow.lib.HadoopFileSystem._connect
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Unable to load libjvm
```

I checked my path variables as described in 
http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/

What can I do to fix this problem?
Is it even possible to use the pyarrow.hdfs.connect function on windows?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi Martin! I suggest you seek help from the Arrow community directly rather than on SO.

Comment: Thank you, for your comment.
Sorry, I'm a newbie. Where can I get help from the Arrow Community?

Comment: See the Community menu on http://arrow.apache.org/. I would suggest the user or developer mailing list. There might be a bug; I want to make sure an issue gets opened if needed